# How do I stop a Scheduled Flow from sending Email Alerts even after it is de-activated?

Tags: email, visual-workflow, email-alert, scheduled-flow

I created a scheduled flow that was supposed to fire twice a year and send an email reminder alert to all staff about all their incomplete task for the year. Unfortunately something went wrong and the flow began sending thousands of emails to all staff about all tasks they have. I quickly deactivated the erroneous flow but the email alerts are still being sent. There is nothing under Time-Based Workflows or Paused and Failed Flow Interviews regarding the email alerts so I'm not sure why they are still being sent.

The time between each batch of emails are getting longer and longer but I need to know how many more are queued and how to stop them.

Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Sorry to hear about the issue. I don't know off the top of my head where to tell you to look, but to rule out something else: Are you sure those emails were kicked off by said Flow and that there is not some other code in the org that maybe was originally used, or was in consideration of being used, before (supposedly) being scrapped and the decision made to use the Flow?

Comment: Hi @Moonpie , Yes I'm positive that the emails were fired by the flow since I made a new email template and alert specifically for it. I was told to look at Scheduled Jobs section and remove the scheduled flow job but there are none there. The flow might've finished sending out emails or it could be something else.

Comment: You don't have this Flow on a Sandbox too, with Email Deliverability "all"?

Answer (score 2):

When you send emails, they are not immediately delivered, but instead put into a queue that will be processed over time. Unfortunately, any emails that are committed to the queue will keep on going. You can turn off email deliverability in Setup, but that only affects future sense, as far as I can tell. You might be able to email support if you need the emails cancelled. You should be able to see the logs for pending emails in the Email Logs. See this [help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&language=en_US).